# How to translate a custom token in rules, private message, and other modules

Tags: i18n-l10n, tokens

I made a custom token to use as an email signature in emails sent by the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and private messages (sent using Private Message).

I defined the token as follows:

```
  else if ($type == 'site') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'signature-team':
          $replacements[$original] = t("Best,")."<br>\n".t("My team");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $replacements;
}
```

My site has two languages, **English** and **Japanese**.  I have translated the emails, rules, and tokens into Japanese from English (the main language).

However, even though the subjects and bodies of the emails and private messages appear in Japanese, the token is always rendered in English.  How does token determine which language to use, and how can I get it to pick up my translation in rules, private messages, and elsewhere?

Comment: Is that strings exists in translate interface and do you translate them?

Comment: @zhilevan Yes, and yes.